# Mootools JSON: result outside of method/scope

Tags: javascript, json, mootools

```
var image;
var imgProperties = new Class({
    image: new Array(),
    json: function() {
        var url = protocol + "//" + host + pathname + "/myEchoFile.php";
        var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
            url: url,
            onSuccess: function(img) {
                this.image[0] = img.name;
                this.image[1] = img.width;
                this.image[2] = img.height;
                alert('img.name=' + this.name); //alerts myImage.jpg
            }
        }).post();
        console.log("this.image[0]=" + this.image[0]); //undefined
        //@fixme
        //this.image is undefined
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The request is not synchronous. (hence it's AJAX) It takes time for it to fire off, complete and set the values.

you should refer to your class instance from the onSuccess and have a separate function called, like this:

```
var imgProperties = new Class({

    Implements: [Events,Options],

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
    },

    json: function() {
        new Request.JSON({
            url: "//" + host + pathname + "/myEchoFile.php",
            onSuccess: this.imageLoaded.bind(this)
        }).post();
    },
    imageLoaded: function(data) {
        this.image = [data.name, data.width, data.height];
        this.fireEvent("imageLoaded", this.image);
    }
});
```

also notice the `.bind(this)` on the `onSuccess` function which ensures you point to the class instance and not the global scope (window object?), which is what you were doing before, modifying `window.image`.

to have it work with the anon as you had it would be like this:

```
onSuccess: function(data) {
    this.imageLoaded(data);
}.bind(this)
```

also notice I fire an event called imageLoaded which you can use from the instance:

```
new imgProperties({
    onImageLoaded: function(imageArray) {
        // access imageArray 
        // or just access this.image instead!
        // or export it to your global namespace like before
        window.image = this.image;
        // more code that relies on window.image being defined... 
    }
}).json();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. Now I got the imageProperties inside another class where I could set the image properties for each image. This is a big step forward. Is there a solution to make these properties available in other methods, e.g. in setImageDimensions(imageProperties) Method?

Comment: yes. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/v38Ee/ shows you how to use the imgProperties class as a **mixin** in another class. p.s. you may want to accept the answer too :) if you are dealing with multiple images, having this.image point to the last one is going to be inadequate. i'd consider this.images array or better yet, use `Asset.image(s)` from mootools-more and `onload` events to lazyload your data.